# Multidimensional in_array()

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I'm creating livescore  tennis script. The results are taken in xml format, and parsed through `simplexml_load_file()`. This creates a multidimensional array.

I need to add a "filter" which shows scheduled, inplay, or finished matches. this is done through jquery.

The structure is as so:

```
<league>
 <container>
  <match status="FT | Set 1 | 12:00|">
   ...
  </match>
  <match status="FT | Set 1 | 12:00|">
   ...
  </match>

 </container>
</league>
```

As I loop through, the file, i output a `league` div box, and then inside this all the matches in a table. The table rows contain the status, which are toggled depending on the filter.

Now, When I filter I can toggle the row, but not the div box. How can I check if the league contains only FT, Only Set* or a format of time before looping through . This way if it only contains one type of status, I can give it a class and toggle the league as well instead of having an empty div.

Comment: You know that you can pass the XML to jQuery via Ajax and do the work with jQuery? I don't know how large the XML is, but if not overly large this might be an option for you. If you need to solve on the PHP side, you should also show your code so far, because I have problems to fully understand your description.

Comment: its pretty large. It takes my php up to 10 seconds seconds to parse it on days with a lot of matches.

Comment: But only because you fetch it from a remote location, don't you? Cache it on the server for some minutes, so you don't need to download it for each request.

Comment: That, and I have to work with this information quite a bit between parsing,  working out what the information means, storing info in a db, and rendering it for the user. Bottom line, I don't really want to change the way I'm doing it because its quite a bit.

Comment: Then I think you should outline your processing in PHP a bit, e.g. with a code-example that shows the place where you hit the roadblock.

Comment: I can't answer my own because of reputation points.
I added a counter to matches. if the category contains matches, i add a class to the category box. in jquery, i used :not selector, which toggles the category boxes without the specific class.

Comment: You should be always able to answer your own questions. Please double check. Let me know if it's still not possible or ask about it on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: You now have 10 reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own.
I added a counter to matches. if the category contains matches, i add a class to the category box. in jquery, i used :not selector, which toggles the category boxes without the specific class.

Just in case someone was looking for a solution to a similar problem.